# Handle DDos with htaccess?

Tags: html, mysql, .htaccess, ddos

at first, I am not really sure if I think correctly about DDos.
When my website gets DDosed, the hacker overload it with requests.
Mostly MySQL for example has to fight against it.
The site starts to lag (?) and then crashes (?).
But thats not my question.

My question is: When I see that I get ddosed, could I simply redirect all pages to a HTML page (like sorrywegetddosed.html) where I tell my users that we will be back soon? :D
Or does the DDos also attack the CPU (?) which would still cause lags?

Sorry and thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDOS attacks are launched from multiple devices. But,DOS attack is on a single internet connections which exhausts the server resources like RAM or CPU. To stop an attack route the server to null or to 127.0.0.1 so all the hits will return back.
So if you are having DDoS attack your resources are not exhausted as in DoS attack.

Comment: But when the DDos attack attacks my server and I redirect through the .htaccess to 127.0.0.1 then it still uses for example my RAM or not? Or do you mean I should change the DNS?

Comment: @Jelly As you redirect the .htacess 127.0.0.1 then your resources like RAM are safe. No need to change the DNS.

Comment: And if I redirect the .htaccess to an HTML file on my website? Would that use much resources?